# React State Button Click is Behind

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I've looked at other solutions but can't seem to incorporate them into my own code.

```
handleMovieClick = pageTransition => {
        if (this.state.moviePage === 1 && pageTransition === '-') {
            this.setState({ moviePage: 1 });
          } else if (pageTransition === '+') {
            this.setState({ moviePage: this.state.moviePage + 1 })
          } else if (pageTransition === '-') {
            this.setState({ moviePage: this.state.moviePage - 1 })
          }
      }
```

above is the setState that is behind by 1, for example, I have to click twice to get to 1. I know it has to do with my state rendering once when clicked and then the state increases, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
this.state = {
            moviePage: 1,
            tvPage: 1
        };
```

Below for the movie trigger

```
<PaginationLink previous href="#toggle-buttons" onClick={()=>
{this.handleMovieClick('-'); this.handleFetchNewMovie(this.props.apiKey, this.state.moviePage)}} />
```

It is an asynchronous call, might be the cause of the 1 step behind for state?

```
handleFetchNewMovie = (apiKey, page = 1) => {
        this.props.postMoviePopular(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&page=${page}&region=US`);
    }
```

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.postMDBConfig(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key=${this.props.apiKey}`);
        this.handleFetchNewMovie(this.props.apiKey);
        this.handleFetchNewTV(this.props.apiKey);
      }
```

Comment: It's going to be nearly impossible to help based upon the code you supplied. [Please create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (via CodeSandbox, or something similar), on top of supplying more code..

Comment: yes we need to see the code for the button that triggers `pageTransition`

Comment: Having some trouble recreating it on CodeSandbox, I will post more of the code if it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You are always seeing a state behind by 1 because `setState` is asynchronous.

In this code:

```
<PaginationLink previous href="#toggle-buttons" onClick={()=>
{this.handleMovieClick('-'); this.handleFetchNewMovie(this.props.apiKey, this.state.moviePage)}} />
```

The `handleMovieClick` happens but `this.state.moviePage` is not the next page yet.

One additional thing to note is that when react state updates depend on the previous state, you should pass a function to `setState` that receives the previous state. You have to do this because of the asynchronous nature of `setState`. [setState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I think it is because according to the setState docs, setState is asynchronous, thus if you put ``` nextPage = state.moviePage + 1 ``` inside of setState, it still functions the same. Thanks anyways @b-rob